# Pandas sum two columns, skipping NaN

Tags: python, pandas

If I add two columns to create a third, any columns containing NaN (representing missing data in my world) cause the resulting output column to be NaN as well. Is there a way to skip NaNs without explicitly setting the values to 0 (which would lose the notion that those values are "missing")?

```
In [42]: frame = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, np.nan], 'b': [3, np.nan, 4]})

In [44]: frame['c'] = frame['a'] + frame['b']

In [45]: frame
Out[45]: 
    a   b   c
0   1   3   4
1   2 NaN NaN
2 NaN   4 NaN
```

In the above, I would like column c to be [4, 2, 4].

Thanks...

Answer (score 77, accepted):

with fillna()

```
frame['c'] = frame.fillna(0)['a'] + frame.fillna(0)['b']
```

or as suggested :

```
frame['c'] = frame.a.fillna(0) + frame.b.fillna(0)
```

giving :

```
    a   b  c
0   1   3  4
1   2 NaN  2
2 NaN   4  4
```

Comment: depending on how big it is, it would probably be better to do `frame.a.fillna(0)` instead

Comment: Thanks. Why should frame.a be preferred over frame['a']? Is it just style preference?

Comment: Using `frame.a.fillna(0)` or `frame['a'].fillna(0)` avoids filling `NaN` terms in columns other than `a`.

Answer (score 56):

Another approach:

```
>>> frame["c"] = frame[["a", "b"]].sum(axis=1)
>>> frame
    a   b  c
0   1   3  4
1   2 NaN  2
2 NaN   4  4
```

Comment: Does sum() automatically do fillna(0) or skip NaNs?

Comment: Yep, it effectively skips them.  Compare `.mean(axis=1)` -- you get a mean of 2 for the second row (index 1), not a mean of 1.0, so it's that it's skipping the NaNs, not that it's imputing a value of 0.

Comment: This may be better as when there are two Nans added together you will get a NaN, and not  a 0, as in the answer above...

Comment: I am using pandas 1.0.5 and it does sum up 2 Nans to 0

Comment: This is the better answer, see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and the `skipna` parameter

Answer (score 25):

As an expansion to the answer above, doing `frame[["a", "b"]].sum(axis=1)` will fill sum of all NaNs as 0

```
>>> frame["c"] = frame[["a", "b"]].sum(axis=1)
>>> frame
    a   b  c
0   1   3  4
1   2 NaN  2
2 NaN   4  4
3 NaN NaN  0
```

If you want the sum of all NaNs to be NaN, you can add the min_count flag as referenced in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)

```
>>> frame["c"] = frame[["a", "b"]].sum(axis=1, min_count=1)
>>> frame
    a   b  c
0   1   3  4
1   2 NaN  2
2 NaN   4  4
3 NaN NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Excellent way to deal with `N/A` values. This solution works for the columns in the same dataframe. Is there any way to deal with columns from different dataframes?

Comment: I think you'll have to concatenate the columns first and then call sum on that concatenated dataframe