# Return Value in the function based on non uniform data in Pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function

I have a pandas dataframe with data structure `(17450 rows * 21 columns)`

```
A       B       C       D ........................... and so on
62.60           
62.90           
62.35           
58.20           
61.75           
61.30           
22.41           
22.43           
21.35           
62.00           
22.72           
14.65           
56.56           
36.06           
21.46           
60.40   84.34   61.35   22.99
61.15   36.33   36.33   
37.31           
19.54           
48.51           
61.70   9.85    9.85    
63.20   119.77  64.65   55.12
61.15   8.09    8.09    
17.30           
21.10           
31.46           
22.30           
59.40           
27.23           
64.25   112.31  65.70   46.61
60.10   7.85    7.85    
37.55           
18.06           
19.89           
17.56           
33.85           
14.34           
21.69           
59.50           
62.90           
62.45           
64.30   96.04   66.00   30.04
62.75   142.22  64.20   78.02
59.95   31.66   31.66   
47.62           
59.86           
20.58           
17.22           
21.08           
44.70           
31.57           
58.55           
61.60           
63.75   109.66  65.25   44.41
61.90   102.31  63.15   39.16
61.30   55.54   55.54   
18.75           
61.00   0.57    0.57    
31.20           
16.17           
12.27           
16.00           
13.84           
59.10           
65.50   115.62  67.20   48.42
64.20   126.65  65.70   60.95
65.40   131.75  66.90   64.85
61.60   14.98   14.98   
58.58           
37.10           
.
.
.
.
(17450 rows * 21 columns)
```

Suppose out of this whole dataframe I want to take the sum of 2 specific columns,
The column A has values in all column,
but the column B has some null/missing values

I want to add these columns A & B
as if

```
A              B               
60.40         61.35           
61.15         36.33           
37.31                         
19.54                         
48.51                         
61.70         9.85
```

when it take sum, the output of sum is only of those rows where value of B is not null, and skip the rows where there is null value in column B

```
A              B                Out
60.40         61.35           121.75
61.15         36.33           97.48
37.31                         
19.54                         
48.51                         
61.70         9.85            71.55
```

either it takes all values of column A, without considering if B is null or not (without adding)

```
A              B                Out         
60.40         61.35           60.40        
61.15         36.33           61.15        
37.31                         37.31 
19.54                         19.54 
48.51                         48.51 
61.70         9.85            61.70
```

The function is

```
def sum(row):
    if np.where((row['B'] >= 0)):
        return (row["A"] + row["B"])
    elif np.where((row['B'] == np.nan)):
        return (row["A"])
    else:
        return np.nan

df_col_merged['Out'] = df_col_merged.apply(lambda row : sum(row), axis=1)
```

The output should be

```
A              B                Out
60.40         61.35           121.75
61.15         36.33           97.48
37.31                         37.31
19.54                         19.54
48.51                         48.51
61.70         9.85            71.55
```

How to change it in the function without changing/replacing/fillna NaN values to zero?
I have to keep the data structure the same (i.e) have to keep the NaN value where they are, as it will change the values in further statistical operations.

Comment: depending on how you parse the NaN values, simply `df.sum(axis=1)` can work as you expect

Comment: note: there are many columns, not just two - it would be sweet if you put a snippet of your dataframe, see best practices to ask questions

Comment: Sorry, @braulio , I have updated the question. I will keep it in mind for future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip nan values look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24387164/7035448, [DataFrame.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) skipna is by default True

```py
df_col_merged[['A', 'B']].sum(axis=1)
```

This will make sure contribution of B is not there if B is nan, and A's contribution always there. So if A is nan then output will be nan

```py
df_col_merged['Out'] = df_col_merged['A'] + df_col_merged['B'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: Isn't there any other alternate just to keep values of column A, where B is NaN, I would have filled the NaN with 0 earlier, but the dataframe is large (having lot of columns) and I have to keep the NaN values where it is in the Column B , and It will disturb other statistical operations, So simply wanted to do so by defining the function only.

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan .sum skips nan values according to `Yep, it effectively skips them. Compare .mean(axis=1) -- you get a mean of 2 for the second row (index 1), not a mean of 1.0, so it's that it's skipping the NaNs, not that it's imputing a value of 0` in comments of https://stackoverflow.com/a/24387164/7035448

Comment: [DataFrame.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) the default for `skipna` is `True` for DataFrame sum. This is the default behaviour but can be changed if needed.

Comment: It worked fine as a single line code, but Just for curiosity, is there any way to put it in the function defined above? Like I also had to replace the 0 to NaN in those rows where both columns had NaN values, which i did as df_col_merged['Out'].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True).

Answer (score 1):

Why is `pd.DataFrame.sum()` not working for you? Perhaps just taking care of the data types should solve it?

Example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[60.40,61.35],
[61.15,36.33],
[37.31,NaN ],
[19.54,NaN ],
[48.51,],
[61.70,9.85 ]], columns=["A", "B"])
```

The data frame is

```
df.info()  

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   A       6 non-null      float64
 1   B       3 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 224.0 bytes
```

Using the sum operator works as expected:

```
df[["A","B"]].sum(axis=1)                                                                                                                                                                              
0    121.75
1     97.48
2     37.31
3     19.54
4     48.51
5     71.55
dtype: float64
```

In my opinion is better practice to leave the data "intact" and let type information do the magic when possible, if that is the expected behaviour. A question is what does the null or empty values mean in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but It do have other columns also, and I just have to take sum of these 2 columns only. Data structure is (17415 rows × 19 columns)

Comment: then simply use `df[["column name 1", "column name 2"]].sum(axis=1)` - the question is how you threat your missing/empty values

Comment: Thanks for your time, @braulio, It worked, but Just for curiosity, is there any way to put it in the function defined above? Like I also had to replace the 0 to NaN in those rows where both the columns had NaN values, which i did as df_col_merged['Out'].replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True).