# How to concatenate two columns ignoring NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
id1    id2
a      NaN
b      c
d      e
```

I want to create new columns ids as a concatenation of id1 and id2:

```
df.ids = df.id1 + "-" + df.id2
```

But result is:

```
id1    id2   ids
a      NaN   NaN
b      c     b-c
d      e     d-e
```

As you see concatenation of a and NaN is NaN, however, I would like to get a-NaN. How to do that? desired result:

```
id1    id2   ids
a      NaN   a-NaN
b      c     b-c
d      e     d-e
```

Comment: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24386638/11342997)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas sum two columns, skipping NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386638/pandas-sum-two-columns-skipping-nan)

Comment: @DatBoi no because with that solution  ids will be a instead of a-NaN

Comment: Since NaN is a floating point number (of sorts), but c and e are strings, you'll need to convert everything to string. Then your concatenation will work.

Comment: Note: I wouldn't phrase it as "sum", but as concatenation. "Sum" tends to refer to the actual values (numbers), certainly in the context of Pandas and NumPy.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id1":['a', 'b', 'c'], "id2":[np.nan, 'c', 'e']})
df['ids'] = df.id1.replace(np.nan, 'NaN') + "-" + df.id2.replace(np.nan, 'NaN')
print(df)

>   id1  id2    ids
> 0   a  NaN  a-NaN
> 1   b    c    b-c
> 2   c    e    c-e
```

I think you can replace the np.nan before the sum.

Comment: This is nicer in a way, since the other two solutions results in a standard "nan" string. This solution lets the user pick the formatting of the NaN.

Comment: But use `df.id2.fillna('NaN')` to be even clearer and shorter.

Comment: @9769953 Nice method, that's what NumPy wants us to do to deal with np.nan. Cool function. :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
df['ids'] = df['id1'].astype(str) + "-" + df['id2'].astype(str)
```

Output:

```
  id1  id2    ids
0   a  NaN  a-nan
1   b    c    b-c
2   d    e    d-e
```

Another way would be to first convert NaN to string by using `.fillna()`:

```
df['id2'].fillna('NaN', inplace = True)
df['ids'] = df['id1'] + "-" + df['id2']
```

Output:

```
  id1  id2    ids
0   a  NaN  a-NaN
1   b    c    b-c
2   d    e    d-e
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'id2': [np.NaN, 'c', 'e']})
df['id2'] = df['id2'].astype(str)
df['ids'] = df['id1'] + "-" + df['id2']
df
```

Result:

```
  id1  id2    ids
0   a  nan  a-nan
1   b    c    b-c
2   c    e    c-e
```

Alternatively, use:

```
df['id2'] = df['id2'].fillna('NaN')
```

instead of the type conversion. This way, you get to pick the exact string (including capitalization) you want for the NaNs.

Answer (score 0):

Given a number *a*, I would say that you cannot perform *a-NaN*, as **NaN** stands for "Not a Number".

If you just want to skip NaN as if they were 0s', you'll need to filter them (as done  [in this other case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124376/convert-nan-value-to-zero)).

Comment: The OP clearly wants a string representation of the NaNs concatenated to the other column's value.

Comment: Yep, I noticed after reading your answers/comments. When the OP used the word sum, I got confused